# JavaScript function works.. but not in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, for-loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  botManager();
};
```

only executes once

```
botManager();
botManager();
botManager();
```

but this executes 3 times. I'm baffled. I've tried debugging with console.log and debugger; but to no avail. What are common solutions?

Comment: you want botManager to execute 100 times?  or wht?

Comment: seems like your botManager function calling other functions which are taking too long to complete while the loop execution is quite faster as a result you are not getting any result.. you can add timeout function to add some delay and if botManager return some result you can use chaining to make them synchronous...

Comment: change your `i` to 3 and try to step through your code

Comment: You could start with an empty implementation of botManager and add more code along the way until you see the current behavior.

Comment: `for` loop will just break if the nested functions haven't finished their job by the time `botManager()` is called again by the `for` loop (which is 1 ms)

Comment: @RohitS What on earth are you talking about? That is not how JavaScript works at all.

Comment: @siam Same question I have for RohitS: what on earth are you talking about? JavaScript simply does not work the way the two of you are saying it works.

Comment: @MichaelGeary yes it does. try to load different images/ do an ajax request in a for loop.

Comment: @siam Now you are talking about asynchronous callback functions. There is no asynchronous callback shown in the question. The code *in the question* is synchronous and deterministic. You mentioned 1 millisecond - in fact the loop will run much faster than that, but that will not cause any problem. You may well be right that the code the OP *did not show* involves some ajax calls, but here we are reading between the lines. It's important to understand that the code as shown in the question does not have this issue, that the problem could only be in code that is *not* shown.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I din't answer the question tho. just gave the OP a suggestion (or possible scenario) that could've been the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry if my coments seem a little hot-headed. :-) I just think it's important to understand how JavaScript code really works, and to understand that issues with asynchronous callbacks do not mean that the simple code shown in the question may not run reliably. JavaScript doesn't get "busy" and forget how to run a loop. :-) In other words, it's not a question of `botManager` "taking too long to complete" as @RohitS said. And "chaining" has no effect on whether functions run synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: @MichaelGeary its ok I understand :) and just so you know, its not just for async function, if you try to do any CPU intensive work (like 2D/3D canvas drawing) in a `for` loop its also not gonna work.

Comment: @siam No, really, being CPU intensive does not mean that an ordinary `for` loop will not work as expected. Suppose `botManager()` contains some kind of inner loop that takes a full second to execute: this will not cause the outer `for` loop to have unexpected behavior. Of course if the entire script takes too long to execute, the browser may pop up a message asking if you want to terminate the script. But it won't just silently fail to work as expected. If there is an asynchronous callback involved, that of course is a different story.

Comment: @MichaelGeary (well, i am on same earth where we all are..:) ) i guess i tried putting a suggestion.. i didn't mentioned in any case javascript will forget to do something or it did.. also can you explain what has resolved the problem in this case by simply using 'let' keyword

Comment: @MichaelGeary sorry if my comment appear to be rude..but i really want to know how the problem got sorted here.. :D

Comment: same thing here too; again being ignorant and impolite by not responding to comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give scope to loop variables

```
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

Everywhere you are using for loops. Or better yet use `'use strict'` at start of page.

Because if you have other(s) for loops that use **i** in the functions that are being called inside the main for loop, then that could be causing problems.

Comment: Thank you, jesus. 'Let' works great and now Ill try strict. I had no idea let even existed.. knew I was missing something though!

Comment: While this may solve the problem, it doesn't help in *understanding* the problem. The code as shown in the question cannot possibly have the problem as stated. JavaScript does not get "busy" or "tired" and "forget" how to run a loop. It just doesn't work that way. The problem lies elsewhere, in code that was not shown in the question. Now, if some of that other code is asynchronous code that depends on the value of `i`, that is a different matter. But we can't possibly know that from the code shown in the question.

Comment: Also the browser support of the `let` should be taken into account.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Yes, I'm sorry about that. I tried to guess what was going on but I couldn't post my guessing as a comment because I lacked enough reputation points back then so I didn't have any other option but to post an answer.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos My answer was edited. Previously I had **var i** and after the edition it became **let i**.

Comment: @Ditto yeah, ok. I just thought that @Jacobjanak should know. For me `let` is ok, anyone should have the latest browser for security reasons.